# MESSAGE: Undefined Variable using data array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using data array to transfer data from a database and it shows an error message given below...

> A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED SEVERITY: NOTICE MESSAGE:UNDEFINED VARIABLE: 
>       VOYAGE_INFO FILENAME: CLIENT/MANIFEST.PHP 
>       FILE:C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\PHIVIDEC\APPLICATION\VIEWS\PORT\CLIENT\MANIFEST.PHP 
>       LINE:40 FUNCTION:_ERROR_HANDLER –

Here's my code:

```
public function manifest() {
    $this->Auth->authCheck();
    $data = $this->template();

    $data_array = array(
        'voyage_info' =>$this->PortManifestModel->get_voyage()->result(),
    );

    // your code here

    $this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data, $data_array);
}
```

In my view page:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg  col-md-4 m-2 btn-cus" href="">
    <?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?>
        <h3>Voyage <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3> 
        <small>Schedule</small>
    <?php }  ?>
</a>
```

What do I need to do to solve this?

Comment: Please paste here complete error message.

Comment: A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

SEVERITY: NOTICE

MESSAGE:UNDEFINED VARIABLE: VOYAGE_INFO

FILENAME:CLIENT/MANIFEST.PHP

FILE:C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\PHIVIDEC\APPLICATION\VIEWS\PORT\CLIENT\MANIFEST.PHP LINE:40
FUNCTION:_ERROR_HANDLER

Comment: Please also add files name of codes. Also mention which one is line 40 of file MANIFEST.PHP?

Comment: line 40 is  <?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?> mate, under manifest.php

Comment: php didnt recognized the variable i created in  controller

Answer (score 0):

Data has to be passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the **second parameter** of the view loading method. So when controller loads view it find data in the second parameter.

Whereas in second `$data` you didn't provide data, rather you are trying to pass it the third parameter

Please update your code as given below...

**From**

```
$this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data, $data_array);
```

**To**

```
$this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data_array);
```

Regarding the third parameter of view please check details from official 
[Source](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data) given below...

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the method so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it
>   to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in
>   some way. If you set the parameter to TRUE (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

Comment: but the $data = $this->template(); is need for the template of the page

Comment: For this problem, I will recommend you to lunch and another post. and post its link here, I will tell you the solution. And before that please mark this post as solved if your problem is solved.