# How can I call data (array) which is in controller transfer to view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to transfer data array from the controller to view the page but I already declared a variable ($data) that transfer to the view page.

How can I transfer 2 or more variable in the controller

Here's my code

Controller

```
public function manifest() {
    $this->Auth->authCheck();
    $data = $this->template();

    $data_array = array(

    'voyage_info' => $this->PortManifestModel->get_voyage()->result(),

    );

    // your code here
    $this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data);
}
```

view page

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary primary-bg btn-lg  col-md-4 m-2 btn-cus" href="#">

       <?php foreach($voyage_info as $voyage) {  ?>
           <h3>Voyage <?=$voyage->voyage_number?></h3>
           <small>Schedule</small>                                                     
     <?php }  ?>                                                              
  </a>
```

I want to get `voyage_info` or more data in view page, not just `$data`.
By the way, $data is for the template so I need it as well.

Comment: just add it in another index `$data['whatever_name_that_is'] = $another_data_here`, and just do the same for another

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890662/message-undefined-variable-using-data-array/51890935

Answer (score 2):

do like this

**In controller**

```
$data['template'] = $this->template();
$data['voyage_info'] = $this->PortManifestModel->get_voyage()->result();

$this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data);
```

**In View**

```
$template # -> have your template data
$voyage_info # -> has your model data
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a work around that I sometimes use, it's by creating an empty view file and then passing the data to that view.

Step 1 - Create a view `empty.php` in views folder and don't put any contents in it.

Step 2 - call the view load before your normal view loads.

```
$this->load->view("empty", $data);
$this->load->view("port/client/manifest", $data);
```

Comment: You're welcome. In case you find an answer that meets your requirments, you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer. Cheers.